# Sort by name elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I try to sort my documents per name using elastic search & the official php client  , how i can proceed ?

```
    $params = [
        'index' => $this->index ,
        'type' => 'videos',
        'from' => $this->uri->segment(2),
        'size' => 12,
        'body' => [
        'query' => [
        'filtered' => [
            'filter' => [
                'term' => [ 'name' => $query ] ,
                'term' => [ 'tags' => $query ]
              ]
           ]
        ]
      ]
    ];




    $data['results'] = $this->client->search($params);
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is over a year old, but the answer is not easy to find on the internet, so I'll answer it anyway.
To specify the field to sort on and the order to sort in, use the following syntax:

```
$params['sort'] = array('updated_at:desc');
```

To sort on multiple fields:

```
$params['sort'] = array('updated_at:desc', 'user_id:asc', ...);
```

Answer (score 4):

I just saw this post while searching for an answer to the same question, in my case the solution was much simpler and different to the ones I saw here.

```
$params['body']['sort'] = [ 'id' => 'desc']
```

this worked fine for me using `"elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^6.1"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$params = [
        'index' => $this->index ,
        'type' => 'videos',
        'from' => $this->uri->segment(2),
        'size' => 12,
        'body' => [
        'query' => [
        'filtered' => [
            'filter' => [
                'term' => [ 'name' => $query ] ,
                'term' => [ 'tags' => $query ]
              ]
           ]
        ],
        'sort' => [
            'name' => [
                'order' => 'asc'
            ]
        ]
      ]
    ];
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html

Comment: Nope, sort must be a subelement of query. BTW, no need for order => array(...). Just write directly field_name => asc

Answer (score 0):

If you have unanalyzed [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) you must use it without enabling fielddata:

```
$params = [
        'index' => $this->index ,
        'type' => 'videos',
        'from' => $this->uri->segment(2),
        'size' => 12,
        'body' => [
        'query' => [
        'filtered' => [
            'filter' => [
                'term' => [ 'name' => $query ] ,
                'term' => [ 'tags' => $query ]
              ]
           ]
        ],
        'sort' => [
            'name' => [
                'order.keyword' => 'asc'
            ]
        ]
      ]
    ];
```

But if you haven't the unanalyzed keyword you should reset your index mapping to enable fielddata to name field:

```
    curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
    {
      "properties": {
        "name": { 
          "type":     "text",
          "fielddata": true
        }
      }
    }

'
```

see : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html