# elasticsearch 5.2 sorting with ICU plugin needs fielddata = true?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to sort elasticsearch result documents with icu_collation filter. So I have
settings for index:

```
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "ducet_sort": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [ "icu_collation" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and mappings

```
"mappings": {
    "card": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "sort": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "ducet_sort",
              "index": false
            }
          }
        }
}}}
```

and query:

```
{
      "sort": ["title.sort"]
}
```

But query failed:

```
"caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [title.sort] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory."
        }
```

In documentation the suggested data type for sorting is **keyword**. But data type **keyword** doesn't support analyzer. In addition the fielddata is not recommended:

[documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/fielddata.html#_fielddata_is_disabled_on_literal_text_literal_fields_by_default)

So is there a way for sorting documents in elasticsearch with some specific collation e.g. icu_collation **without** fielddata=true?

Thank you.

Comment: Before you enable fielddata, consider why you are using a text field for aggregations, sorting, or in a script. It usually doesn’t make sense to do it. So, why you need it?

Comment: I need sorting by icu_collation. How can I do it with different data type e.g. keyword?

Comment: they just propose to enable fielddata https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-icu-collation.html

Comment: Check this similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807737/sort-by-name-elasticsearch/56507111#56507111

Answer (score 0):

In Kibana, open *Dev Tools* option from left menu and execute the query below after update according to your settings.

```
PUT _mapping/INDEX_NAME?update_all_types
{
  "properties": {
    "FIELD_NAME": {
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}
```

or through *Curl* or a terminal like *Cygwin*(for Windows) execute the query below after update according to your settings.

```
curl -XPUT http://DOCKER_MACHINE_IP:9200/INDEX_NAME -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "type": {
      "properties": {
        "FIELD_NAME": {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```