# ElasticSearch sort gives fielddata error

Tags: firebase, elasticsearch, firebase-realtime-database, elasticsearch-5

I'm using Firebase Flashlight to query my Firebase database, but I'm not able to sort my results.

I'm using this query:

```
this.elasticConfig = {
  type: 'guest',
  body: {
    from: 0,
    size: 20,
    query: {
      bool: {
        must: [
          {
            match: {
              isApproved: false
            }
          },
          {
            match: {
              isCheckedIn: false
            }
          },
          {
            match: {
              eventId: event.id
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    sort: [
      {
        name: {
          order: 'asc'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

But I'm getting this error from elasticsearch:

```
Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.
```

I find it strange that a simple alphabetical sort operation would require you to use "significant memory".

Have I missed something in my query? Or is there something else I can do in order to make it work?

Comment: What ES version is this?

Comment: Also, try sorting on `name.keyword` if this is ES 5 and the field has been automatically mapped by Elasticsearch. Otherwise you need to have the `name` field as `keyword`, add a `keyword` sub-field to it to search on `name.keyword`.

Comment: @AndreiStefan That worked :) Feel free to add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Check this similar answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807737/sort-by-name-elasticsearch/56507111#56507111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try sorting on `name.keyword` if this is ES 5 and the field has been automatically mapped by Elasticsearch. Otherwise you need to have the `name` field as `keyword` type or add a `keyword` sub-field to it to search on `name.keyword` and, of course, have the subfield to be of type `keyword`.