# Elasticsearch how to set fielddata: true for all text fields

Tags: database, elasticsearch, nosql

Can somebody tell me please how to set fielddata true for all text fields. I need to sort according them and it throws me an error **Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default** Here is piece of mapping where street or city are text fields which throws me this error.

```
"address": {
                    "properties": {
                        "city": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "boost": 5,
                            "analyzer": "suggestion"
                        },
                        "zip": {
                            "type": "text"
                        },
                        "street": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "boost": 7,
                            "analyzer": "suggestion"
                        }
```

Comment: I'm curious why you need to sort according to fielddata. Can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve? Some sample data maybe?

Comment: What is curious on sorting data? I edit the question.

Comment: There's a reason why it is not advised to sort on fielddata. Hence my question... If you're sorting on zip, then zip should be a keyword field. Sorting on street (multi tokens) and city (also multi token) might not get you the sorting you want.

Comment: As I understand the sorting on multi token fields engine works in different way while sorting. Can you explain me clearly what means "might not get"?

Comment: Check this similar answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807737/sort-by-name-elasticsearch/56507111#56507111

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to update the mapping of your field for this purpose you can use
the put mapping API of elasticsearch.

```
PUT yourindexName/_mapping/_doc
{
  "properties": {
     "yourfield": { 
       "type":     "text",
       "fielddata": true
     }
  }
}
```

Although it is not advisable to enable the fielddata on text fields as they can consume a lot of heap space.

I suggest you to go through this link explaining the rationale behind this in detail. [elasticsearch fielddata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#_enabling_fielddata_on_literal_text_literal_fields)

Also alternatively you can try the below mapping for your fields:

```
 "yourfield": { 
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
```

Instead of plain text only...i hope it will serve your purpose.

Happy coding :)

Comment: But if there will be "yourfiled.keyword" I should rewrite a lot of PHP code which creates the queries. Am I right? Cause previous queries to "yourfield" wont work anymore.

Comment: @Čamo this is the multi-field concept of elasticsearch quoting exact lines from elasticsearch documentation "This is the purpose of multi-fields. For instance, a string field could be mapped as a text field for full-text search, and as a keyword field for sorting or aggregations".

Comment: @Čamo checkout this link from elasticsearch documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/multi-fields.html try it.

Comment: And if I need the type: text only for sorting I dont need set fielddata: true?

Comment: Thanks. I did it this way.

Comment: Where to add these settings, any path?